# Basic Discrete Math Logical Proposition

Tags: boolean-algebra

`If -1 - 1 = 0 then tomorrow is Thursday.`

Why is the answer `True`? `-1 - 1` does not equal `0`.

I seem to be struggling with this concept, and I can't seem to word my question correctly to get a good google explanation for an example like this.

Comment: Google "vacuous truth".

Comment: The logical statement $(P\implies Q)$ is equivalent to the logical statement $(\neg P \vee Q)$.  Here $P$, the statement "$-1-1=0$" is a false statement (*in fields not of characteristic 2*), hence $\neg P$ is a true statement, hence $\neg P\vee Q$ is true regardless what $Q$ is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's for the same reason that we truthfully say "If *that*'s true, then pigs fly!"

Since the *that* is *not* true,  *anything* can be said to follow from it .. and we'd be making a true claim in doing so.

(of course, the *point* of saying "If *that*'s true, then pigs fly!" is to say that the *that* isn't true ... for if anything follows from it, including falsehoods like flying pigs, then that means that the *that* has to be false)